# add a ul dynamically after span element jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to add a ul element dynamically after s span element

```
<div class="class1">
<input class="required" type="checkbox" name="id1" id="id1" title="Required"/>
    <span class="class2">
        <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Some text.......</label>
    </span>                   
</div>
```

I tried the below js code, but its not coming..Can somebody please help me in this

```
$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
$('.required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    input.nextAll("ul.error").remove();
    if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
       $('<ul class="error"><li>Required</li></ul>').insertAfter(input.nextAll(".class2"));
    }
});
});
```

I want the new ul element to be placed below the span but

Thanks

Comment: when is this code executed

Comment: This code is executed on submit of a button..I have updated this in the qn

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p9jJ3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use this statement inside "if" :

```
$('.class2').after('<ul class="error"><li>Required</li></ul>');
```

Comment: Hi..I want the error to be after the <span class="class2"> element

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it looks fine:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#submitBtn').click(function(){

            var error = false;

            $('.required').filter(':visible').each(function () {

                var input = $(this);
                input.nextAll("ul.error").remove();

                if( ! $(this).is(':checked')){
                   $('<ul class="error"><li>Required</li></ul>').insertAfter(input.nextAll(".class2"));

                   error = true;
                }

            });

            if(error)
                return false;

        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="class1">
            <input class="required" type="checkbox" name="id1" id="id1" title="Required"/>
            <span class="class2">
                <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Some text.......</label>
            </span>                   
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="send"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
                $('.required').filter(':visible').each(function () {
                    var input = $(this);
                    input.nextAll("ul.error").remove();
                    if(!this.checked){
                       $(this).next().after($('<ul class="error"><li>Required</li></ul>'));
                       $('<ul class="error"><li>Required</li></ul>').insertAfter(input.nextAll(".class2"));
                    }
                });
```